# Does my golang webserver need to be run as the root user in order to support HTTPS/TLS?

Tags: http, ubuntu, ssl, go, https

I want to use golang's built in `ListenAndServeTLS()` function to serve up my webserver (it's a very simple one), and I need to show it where my keys are stored. The keys are stored in a location only the root user can access (Let's Encrypt did this by default) and I can't listen to port 80 or 443 unless I'm the root user.

Does this mean I have to be running the script as root all the time? Is that not insecure?

Comment: Can not the application binary and the certificates be in the same group?

Comment: that is a Linux problem, no matter with golang.

Answer (score 7):

To blatantly quote the well-written [Caddy FAQ](https://caddyserver.com/docs/faq):

> No. On Linux, you can use setcap to give Caddy permission to bind to
>   low ports. Something like `setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep ./caddy`
>   should work. Consult the man pages of your OS to be certain. You could
>   also use iptables to forward to higher ports.
>
> Privilege de-escalation is another option, but it [is not yet a
>   reliable solution](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/1435). It will be implemented as soon as this becomes a
>   robust possibility. Concerned readers are encouraged to get involved
>   to help this become a reality.

Comment: Are there any tutorials available on this then? I can't seem to find how to use setcap and whatnot.

Answer (score 3):

To add to @ma_il's answer, you can use setcap but you still would have to change the permissions of the cert.

Or build your app then run it as root, example: `go build && sudo ./app`

Comment: Why not just always run it as root then?

Comment: @mickdoe people don't like to do that mainly in case there's a vulnerability in the code that'd give the attacker root access, but in the age of containers and docker, it's not that bad to run your app as root.